# How to disable Spring/Hibernate/Hazelcast joint cache?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hazelcast, distributed-caching

We use `Hazelcast` as our `Hibernate` 2nd level cache manager and we have some configurations for it in our `Spring` context files. Our code is also instrumented by Spring `@Cacheable` annotations (for business level cache) and we configured it to use `Hazelcast`. The problem is that in development environment we have multiple database instances and sometimes we should switch our application between them. Each time we switch to another database we should also restart the Hazelcast to be filled with new data and it is a REALY annoying work :(( This is more annoying when we need to have multiple instances of our application up on different databases! so we need also multiple instances of `Hazelcast`!!

As our code is tightly coupled with cache stuffs, it is so hard to remove cache configurations from the code for new instances. Is there any way to tell `Hazelcast`, `Spring` and `Hibernate` do not use/fill cache in presence of our configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to turn off caching with the Spring and Hibernate configurations. In case of Spring Boot, you can do it by setting the following properties in your `application-dev.properties`:

```
spring.cache.type=NONE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false
```